# Build APK runs but release signed APK fails to call API

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I build an ionic app which is working fine when I run it using `ionic run android` command.

I follow the instruction given in below link, to generate release signed APK
http://ionicframework.com/docs/guide/publishing.html

Release signed APK get generated successfully but when I run the app, it **fails to call API**.

Comment: fails to call API?where is that error form?from log or alert dialog?

Comment: Any Stacktrace?

Comment: you need to modify your proguard files, changes depend on which library you used in your project

Comment: I am getting data as NULL and status -1 in error

Comment: as per my findings there is no  proguard files exists in ionic , it exists in android application @PhanDinhThai

Note : I am using ionic 1